# How to calculate p value from ANOVA function for LMM results?

Tags: r, anova, p-value, linear-model

I have used ANOVA function so that I can get the overall p value of significant factors:

```
> anova(lmer81)
Analysis of Variance Table
                    Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value
sex                  1   0.12   0.118  0.0195
vowel3               2 399.96 199.982 33.0859
Language             2 120.41  60.204  9.9604
sex:vowel3           2  89.73  44.865  7.4227
sex:Language         2 166.93  83.463 13.8084
vowel3:Language      4  48.27  12.067  1.9964
sex:vowel3:Language  4  52.76  13.189  2.1821
```

However, this does not give me p value. Can I ask how I can get p value from this?

Comment: Read `help("pvalues")`.

Comment: Sorry from the help menu, should I use F tests via Kenward-Roger approximation using KRmodcomp? as I think I'm looking for p value of fixed effects.

Comment: That's one possibility.

Comment: I'm guessing, but from your object name it looks like you may have used lme4 functions to fit this model. You might want to see here as to why lme4 doesn't produce p-values http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq

Comment: I know that it's a long debate about p value, but many journals want it.

Comment: Look at the mixed function in the [afex](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/afex/index.html) package.